Apache Not Finding Files When Blank Spaces (%20) Are In Name
I have a folder of PHP files that all contain spaces in the name (which I cannot easily change because they are linked to another program). When the browser sends the request it sends %20 and for some reason Apache returns a 404 error. I've tried giving God level permission to the files folders, turned off SELinux, added AllowEncodedSlashes On with no luck as well.

I found this bugzilla that seems to be the exact error. https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69203 I ended up just renaming the files.
